# TypeScript type for value of key in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, definitelytyped

I'm trying to define custom typings for a navigation library using TypeScript, and I haven't wrapped my head around creating a `navigate` function that takes the Screen's name as a first argument, and the Screen's properties as a second argument while still being type safe.

I'm trying to:

1. Safely type the screen name (`keyof Stack`) as a first argument
2. Safely encapsulate my two navigation stacks (`navigate<LoginStack>('HomeScreen')` should never work, only the screens from `LoginStack` should be possible)
3. Use the correct arguments for the corresponding screen name (`keyof Stack`) as the second argument

My current approach:

`ScreenDefinitions.ts`:

```js
export interface LoginStackScreens {
    LoginScreen: BaseProps & { isHeadless?: boolean };
    ForgotPasswordScreen: BaseProps & { email: string };
}
export interface HomeStackScreens {
    HomeScreen: BaseProps & { isHeadless?: boolean };
    SavedScreen: BaseProps;
    ChatsListScreen: BaseProps;
    MyProfileScreen: BaseProps;
    PostDetailsScreen: BaseProps & {
        post: Post;
    };
    // ... some more
}
```

`Navigation.ts`:

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
function navigate<Stack extends HomeStackScreens | LoginStackScreens>(screenName: keyof Stack, props: ValueOf<Stack>): void {
    // Navigation logic
}

navigate<HomeStackScreens>('HomeScreen', {});
```

While I achieved points **1.** and **2.**, the second parameter (arguments) aren't safely typed as they contain **all values** from the `HomeStackScreens` stack:

[image: Screenshot of VSCode showing all types of arguments]

Whereas I only want to have `BaseProps & { isHeadless?: boolean }` in this case (See `HomeStackScreens` definition)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this!

```
function navigate<Stack extends {}>(
  screenName: keyof Stack,
  props: Stack[typeof screenName]
) {
  // Implementation
}
```

Example,

```
type SomeStack = {
  someScreen: {
    test: string
  }
}

navigate<SomeStack>('someScreen', {
  test: 5 // Fails - should be a string!
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I define the `NavigationProp` interface with it's functions, see: https://imgur.com/a/i9Ck3pv

Comment: It looks like TypeScript is fine with it, and ESLint is getting confused. Maybe just turn off ESLint for that line!

Comment: You're right, only ESLint's fault. But the typing for the arguments still don't work, somehow the types are resolved as every argument for every route in the Stack OR (`|`) unknown. See: https://imgur.com/a/LorEtuu

Comment: Try this - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwG7AOZzMAexAB4BlMRAa2QgA9IQATAZ2QG8BfAPnYChlkABwCuzABYAKZgigQIIdAFsIALmSUIATwIxk5KgBohUAoOZr9CSgG0wmwRB3Jps+UogBdAJRq4ITQDcvBy8vAhEzGDIohDoWLiQyAC8yGQUVjT08izs3BI+aJg4eIQklpQ8STwA9ABUyLJwADbIwIqCTRDK4CVEyGLQKLXVyCDCTU0AhKF2DnoEyuXJfALMCxCkMnIgamz8AsiQkWqRUKDY+yEhYRFRIEUJpcsxccWQZOvlXPlB9-G9IAAdCJxBIAORrRZbeRgox7ARHMBqACsyGqIwAYnBgE1WABaZxiAjjRjIABGKDgzjAZxA2GmHC8vCAA

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't really make my arguments type safe. While it only accepts arguments defined in the `SomeStack` type, it does accept **all** of them. So Also for other screens. See my next comment for playground demo link

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwG7AOZzMAexAB4BlMRAa2QgA9IQATAZ2QG8BfAPnYChlkABwCuzABYAKZgigQIIdAFsIALmSUIATwIxk5KgBohUAoOZr9CSgG0wmwRB3Jps+UogBdAJRq4ITQDcvBy8vAhEzGDIohDoWLiQyAC8yGQUVjT08izs3BI+aJg4eIQklpQ8STwA9ABUyLJwADbIwIqCTRDK4CVEyGLQKLXVyCDCTU0AhKF2DnoEyuXJfALMCxCkMnIgamz8AsiQkWqRUKDY+xwG+2vKAPJgA1CbrjsrBzAEBGoARl+dfku1xCYQiURARQSpWWMTixUgZHW5S4+SCEPivRAADoROIJAByW4bLbyfFGPYCI5gNT4gAqEEiZP2n2+hygwggwK8vHR8NKONEkkJ6weTxe2zJ7xZajA7IgwS8QSAA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwG7AOZzMAexAB4BlMRAa2QgA9IQATAZ2QG8BfAPnYChlkABwCuzABbEAKjXoQmrShACeBGMnJUuACmYIoEOegC2EAFzJJAGiFQCg5uY0JKAbUkBdAJTm4IJQG5eDl5eBCJmMGRRCHQsXEhkAF5kMgpnGQYWdm4tbzRMHDxCEidKHkSeAHoAKmR9OAAbZGAjQQaIE3AiomQxaBRqyuQQYQaGgEIQsCVBFFICE1KkvgFmBYhSPQMQczZ+AWRICPMIqFBsfY5LfbWTAHkwPqhN-Tld-YEYAgJzACNv9q+S7XYKhcKREAFeLFZbRWKFSBkdalbSeQKQuLdEAAOhE4i0AHJbhstnICdY9gIjmBzATJBAIuT9pUhgABMDMAC0dFmCDA3Kgtig+y+P0OUGEECCnl4GIRxVxojEhOJDyeL225JWyBZyHZXJ5ED5AqF+2ptPpjOun2+5jAEqlHDRvCAA

Comment: Since this infers the generic type argument, this works perfectly. marking as accepted, thanks